# How to build Postfix from Debian Salsa Git? (gbp:error: upstream/3.3.2 is not a valid treeish)

Tags: debian, git, postfix, packaging

I would like to rebuild the Debian package 'postfix'. Without anything fancy, so no local patches and unsigned packages are fine.

Here's what I tried:

1. Install some dependencies:

   ```
   $ apt install fakeroot git-buildpackage
   $ apt build-dep postfix
   ```

   (Postfix on my build machine is the same/similar available as version I'm trying to build, so this should install most of the build dependencies just fine. I don't have any build dependency issue as well.)
2. Clone the Debian sources:

   ```
   $ git clone https://salsa.debian.org/postfix-team/postfix-dev.git
   ```

   At the time of writing this points to c21140525af28be0e1bacd932e85b96babe6ca98 (tag: v3.3.2-4).
3. cd into the clone:

   ```
   $ cd postfix-dev
   ```
4. IIUC, I should now be able to build the package with a command like

   ```
   $ gbp buildpackage -uc -us
   ```

   (With the two options to make unsigned packages.)

However, the last step results in the error:

```
gbp:error: upstream/3.3.2 is not a valid treeish
```

Answer (score 1):

This piece of software (Postfix) seems not to be sourced from an upstream git, but manually imported in tags in that repository. The tag `v3.3.2` seems to reflect the upstream sources (it does not contain a `debian/` directory).

It seems that this repository does not conform to the default tag name in the `upstream/<version>` format, which is probably a bug or personal preference by the maintainers.

Please refer to the [manpage of git-buildpackage](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/git-buildpackage/gbp-buildpackage.1.en.html) for the below two options:

> ```
> --git-upstream-tree=[BRANCH|SLOPPY|TAG|TREEISH]
>     How to find the upstream sources used to generate the tarball.
>     TAG (the default) [...]
>
> --git-upstream-tag=TAG-FORMAT
>     Use this tag format when looking for tags of upstream versions to build the
>     upstream tarballs. Default is upstream/%(version)s. [...]
> ```

This means that you can manually point to any head in git to what the upstream branch is. The command

```
$ gbp buildpackage --git-upstream-tag='v%(version)s' -us -uc
```

will build the Postfix packages just fine!

*Important! You may need to completely clean the git repository or else you might run into failures regarding checks on locally modified files even if `git status` tells you everything is clean.*

---

For a little bit more efficient fetching for automated builds, here's a recipe to build Postfix by only fetching what's necessary:

```
# Fetch Debian-version tag (notice the -<digit> suffix).
$ git clone -b v3.3.2-4 --depth 1 https://salsa.debian.org/postfix-team/postfix-dev.git
$ cd postfix-dev

# Fetch the upstream tag
$ git fetch --depth 1 origin refs/tags/v3.3.2:refs/tags/v3.3.2

# Because we're not on 'master' (not on any branch actually), we need to add
# the --git-ignore-branch option.
$ gbp buildpackage --git-upstream-tag='v%(version)s' --git-ignore-branch -us -uc
```